# Parsing data via variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I have some code which does some serial communication with some hardware and then reads back some data (as as `std::string`).

```cpp
  std::string data = cmd_exe("gmov");
  char cmdReadback[4];
  uint32_t Speed;
  uint8_t uSpeed;
  uint16_t Accel;
  uint16_t Decel;
  uint32_t AntiplaySpeed;
  uint8_t uAntiplaySpeed; 
  cpMemReadback(cmdReadback, data, 0);
  cpMemReadback(Speed, data, 4);
  cpMemReadback(uSpeed, data, 8);
  cpMemReadback(Accel, data, 9);
  cpMemReadback(Decel, data, 11);
  cpMemReadback(AntiplaySpeed, data, 13);
  cpMemReadback(uAntiplaySpeed, data, 17);
```

where `cpMemReadback` is quite trivial:

```cpp
static constexpr auto cpMemReadback = [](auto& reg, std::string& s, size_t ix) {
  std::memcpy(&reg, s.data()+ix, sizeof(reg));
};
```

There are still some ugly things in this code - but what's bugging me most, is this useless call of `cpMemReadback` and then tracking of the index. I'd like to write:

```cpp
parse_data(data, cmdReadback, Speed, uSpeed, ...);
```

I know that I'd want to use variadic templates, I presumably need a template parameter to track the index and then a parameter pack for my variables and then recursively execute the code, incrementing my index tracking template parameter. I'm just too stupid to actually write the code.

Comment: I'd try to `std::tie` those parameters, and then `std::apply` a variadic lambda on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you might have:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void parseData(const std::string& data, Ts&... args)
{
    [[maybe_unused]]std::size_t idx = 0;
    ((cpMemReadback(args, data, idx), idx += sizeof (Ts)), ...);
}
```

and then replace

```
cpMemReadback(cmdReadback, data, 0);
cpMemReadback(Speed, data, 4);
cpMemReadback(uSpeed, data, 8);
cpMemReadback(Accel, data, 9);
cpMemReadback(Decel, data, 11);
cpMemReadback(AntiplaySpeed, data, 13);
cpMemReadback(uAntiplaySpeed, data, 17);
```

by

```
parse_data(data,
           cmdReadback,
           Speed,
           uSpeed,
           Accel,
           Decel,
           AntiplaySpeed,
           uAntiplaySpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I'd want to use variadic templates, I presumably need a template parameter to track the index and then a parameter pack for my variables and then recursively execute the code, incrementing my index tracking template parameter.

That's a perfectly valid way to approach this, although tracking `idx` in a template parameter is a bit overkill. Doing it as a regular parameter would be fine as well.

Here's what you had in mind looks like:

```cpp
template<std::size_t idx=0, typename First, typename... Rest>
void parse_data(const std::string& data, First& first, Rest&... rest) {
    // Handle the first element in the list
    cpMemReadback(first, data, idx);

    // Recurse with the rest if there are any
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Rest) > 0) {
      parse_data<idx + sizeof(First)>(data, rest...);
    }
}
```

The only drawback that this has over the other answer's fold-expression + comma operator approach is that it can *theoretically* lead to deeper stacks and slightly larger executable sizes.

I say theoretically because any modern compiler would almost certainly optimise these away in non-0 optimisation levels. So this would only really be a factor if you run this code in debug mode on architectures with aggressive memory constraints.

You can find a demonstration of the difference, and lack thereof in `-O1` here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xbn35ecc8

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same problem. Working with a robot using serial communications. There are many, many message formats so I needed a way to map each message to the types in the message. Then based on the type convert the message `uint8_t` bytes to the type.

It uses a `tuple` of types that list the expected types in the message. Each type adjusts the position pointer in the message. The code demonstrates handling the incoming message in a loop or individual pieces.

It works with C++17 and C++20. This was my "get it working code" so there is some general output for watching whats happening. I did some refinements in the real code but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Live version [here](https://onlinegdb.com/J36K3fZ9J).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>

using Msg = std::basic_string<std::uint8_t>;
//==========================================================================================================================================
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator( )...;
};

#if (_cplusplus != 202002L)    // check for C++17 or C++20
// Deduction guide, google `CTAD for aggregates` for more info
template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;    // not needed before C++20
#endif

auto emit = overloaded {
    [](const auto& b) {
        std::cout << "From auto: " << std::boolalpha << b << std::noboolalpha << '\n';
    },

    [](const char& b) {
        std::cout << "From char: ";
        if (std::isprint(b)) {
            std::cout << std::showbase << b;
        } else if (b != 0) {
            std::cout << '\\' << (uint16_t(b) & 0xFF);
        } else {
            std::cout << '\\' << 0;    // showbase does not output 0x for zero
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    },

    [](const uint8_t& b) {
        std::cout << "From uint8_t: " << std::showbase << (uint16_t)b << '\n';
    },

    [](const int8_t& a) {
        std::cout << "From int8_t: " << int16_t(a) << '\n';
    },

    [](const uint16_t& a) {
        std::cout << "From uint16_t: " << std::showbase << a << '\n';
    },
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class... Ts>
struct msg_proc : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator( )...;
};

#if (__cplusplus != 202002L)
// Deduction guide, google `CTAD for aggregates` for more info
template <class... Ts>
msg_proc(Ts...) -> msg_proc<Ts...>;    // not needed from C++20

#endif

auto load = msg_proc {
    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, bool& value) {
        value = (msg[pos++] != 0);
    },

    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, char& value) {
        value = msg[pos++];
    },

    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, uint8_t& value) {
        value = msg[pos++];
    },

    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, int8_t& value) {
        value = msg[pos++];
    },

    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, int16_t& value) {
        value = (msg[pos] << 8) + msg[pos + 1];
        pos += 2;
    },

    [](Msg const& msg, int16_t& pos, uint16_t& value) {
        value = (msg[pos] << 8) + msg[pos + 1];
        pos += 2;
    },

};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename... Ts>
void emitter(std::tuple<Ts...> tup) {
    std::apply([](const auto&... e) {
        (emit(e), ...);
    },
        tup);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void emitter(T const& value) {
    emit(value);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename... Ts>
auto converter(Msg const& msg) {
    std::tuple<Ts...> tup { };
    int16_t pos { };

    std::apply(
        [&](auto&... e) {
            (load(msg, pos, e), ...);
        },
        tup);
    std::cout << "pos " << pos << '\n';
    return tup;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( ) {
    Msg msg { 0x01, 1, 0x57, 0x58, 0x12, 0x34, 0xDE, 0xAD };

    auto& b_c = converter<bool, char, uint8_t, int8_t, int16_t, uint16_t>;
    auto res = b_c(msg);

    emitter(res);
    std::cout << '\n';

    emitter(std::get<0>(res));
    emitter(std::get<1>(res));
    emitter(std::get<2>(res));
    emitter(std::get<3>(res));
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```